# How do i make amChart ForceDirected div scrollable so I can see all available nodes?

Tags: javascript, zooming, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using amCharts to create a Network chart. When my dataset starts to grow, node are being hid from the "chart div". How can I make it scrollable, xaxis and yaxis. Does it support zoom? I've read the documentation but zoom is not mentioned.

Thanks!

```
#chartdiv {
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2jpkq6fh/